# Error when entering Facebook login in iPhone App

Tags: xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to integrate the Facebook API in my iOS app, but am getting the following error:

> WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the
>   webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:
>   delegate:  Application tried to present
>   modally an active controller .

How can I solve this error?

**Here is my code:**

```
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

NSString *redirectUrlString = @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
NSString *authFormatString = @"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&type=user_agent&display=touch";

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:authFormatString, _apiKey, redirectUrlString, _requestedPermissions];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

For checking the login credential, i am writing the below code inside the function `logincheck`

```
if  ([urlString rangeOfString:@"login.php"].location != NSNotFound) 
{
     [_delegate displayRequired];
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code leading up to this error?

Comment: @cppl i have added the code which causes the error.